# GridBagLayout and JButtons

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I haven't found an answer or maybe I don't understand and answer. What I'm trying to do is display 2 buttons ion one row spaced separated by one or two spaces. When I do this with labels and text fields it works perfectly but with buttons no such luck,

```
gridBagConstraints.weighty = 0.1;
gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1;

gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
gridBagConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
gridBagConstraints.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
add(streetLabel, gridBagConstraints);

gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
gridBagConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
gridBagConstraints.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
add(streetField, gridBagConstraints);
```

Works great!

```
gridBagConstraints.weighty = 2.0;
gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1;

gridBagConstraints.gridy = 4;
gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
gridBagConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;

gridBagConstraints.insets = new Insets(0 , 0, 0, 5);
add(addBtn, gridBagConstraints, 0);

gridBagConstraints.weighty = 2.0;
gridBagConstraints.weightx = 0.1;

gridBagConstraints.gridy = 4;
gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 0;
gridBagConstraints.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
gridBagConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
add(cancelBtn, gridBagConstraints);
```

Not so Great.

[image]

Comment: Thank you all for responding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you remove all uses of `weightx` and `weighty`.  They are not doing what you think.

The weights only apply when there is *extra space* in your grid.  They are not applicable to your form.

Also, `gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 0;` does not make sense;  if something is in the grid, it can’t span zero cells.  gridwidth and gridheight must be positive (or a special value like [REMAINDER](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#REMAINDER) or [RELATIVE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#RELATIVE)).

A good way to accomplish your goal is by nesting a JPanel with a different layout, which contains only your buttons, inside your GridBagLayout:

```
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
buttonPanel.add(addBtn);
buttonPanel.add(cancelBtn);

gridBagConstraints.gridy = 4;
gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
gridBagConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;

gridBagConstraints.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
add(buttonPanel, gridBagConstraints);
```

Notice the use of `GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER` to make the panel span all cells horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's probably possible to do this entire view with a single `GridBagLayout`, I'd combine layouts to make the job easy.

[image]

- The **RED** area would be a panel with a `BorderLayout`. GREEN & BLUE would be panels in the `CENTER` & `PAGE_END` respectively.
- The **GREEN** bordered panel would have a `GridBagLayout`.
- The **BLUE** bordered panel would have a `FlowLayout`.

Answer (score -1):

The highest value for `GridBagConstraints.weighty` is 1. If the value is higher than one, the program will reset it to 0. If you want the value to be greater than 0 and less than 1, then you can use a decimal (ie. 0.5)

Comment: This is completely false.  The weight can be any nonnegative value.  The weights on any single axis are all assumed to be proportional to each other.  And a non-zero weight is never forced to zero.